# LNK2019 (Unresolved external symbol) When Compiling with MSVC2013

Tags: c++, qt, visual-c++

Im working on a project using Qt/C++ originally compiled with MinGW64 (gcc 4.8). I decided to "port" it to MSVC2013, since I need to use some Windows API functions that doesn't work well in MinGW, but right now I'm stuck at this error:

```
mainwindow.obj:-1: error: LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: void __cdecl IMLoginView::clearFieldPass(void)" (?clearFieldPass@IMLoginView@@QEAAXXZ) referenced in function "public: void __cdecl MainWindow::showConnectionErrorDialog(void)" (?showConnectionErrorDialog@MainWindow@@QEAAXXZ)    
imingestinglist.obj:-1: error: LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: static class QString __cdecl IMStorageSystem::getLogDir(void)" (?getLogDir@IMStorageSystem@@SA?AVQString@@XZ) referenced in function "private: class QList<int> __cdecl IMIngestingList::loadList(void)" (?loadList@IMIngestingList@@AEAA?AV?$QList@H@@XZ)
moc_imloginview.obj:-1: error: LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: void __cdecl IMLoginView::login(void)" (?login@IMLoginView@@QEAAXXZ) referenced in function "private: static void __cdecl IMLoginView::qt_static_metacall(class QObject *,enum QMetaObject::Call,int,void * *)" (?qt_static_metacall@IMLoginView@@CAXPEAVQObject@@W4Call@QMetaObject@@HPEAPEAX@Z)
moc_imloginview.obj:-1: error: LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: void __cdecl IMLoginView::handleError(enum ALFRED_ACCESS_ERROR)" (?handleError@IMLoginView@@QEAAXW4ALFRED_ACCESS_ERROR@@@Z) referenced in function "private: static void __cdecl IMLoginView::qt_static_metacall(class QObject *,enum QMetaObject::Call,int,void * *)" (?qt_static_metacall@IMLoginView@@CAXPEAVQObject@@W4Call@QMetaObject@@HPEAPEAX@Z)
moc_imloginview.obj:-1: error: LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: void __cdecl IMLoginView::userDisconnected(void)" (?userDisconnected@IMLoginView@@QEAAXXZ) referenced in function "private: static void __cdecl IMLoginView::qt_static_metacall(class QObject *,enum QMetaObject::Call,int,void * *)"
```

The problem is: These methods aren't part of some external library, but part of the project itself. And I already triple checked that they are implemented. They aren't part of any template class either, but normal classes, and the log says the cpp files are being compiled. The same project links just fine with MinGW64.

I'm currently using Qt Creator 3.3.2 and QT 5.3.2.

What can be happening?

EDIT:

I Can't show much code, since its a closed-source project, but I can at least show the header and implementation layout of the methods:

imloginview.h:

```
class IMLoginView : public QWidget
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit IMLoginView(QWidget *parent = 0);

    void clearFieldPass();

    ~IMLoginView();
private:
    //Lots of attributes

    void configureComponents();
    void keyPressEvent(QKeyEvent *event);
signals:

public slots:
    void login();
    void handleError(ALFRED_ACCESS_ERROR error);
    void userDisconnected();
}
```

imloginview.cpp:

```
IMLoginView::IMLoginView(QWidget *parent) : //lots of initializations here
{
   //Implementation
}

IMLoginView::~IMLoginView()
{
}

void IMLoginView::clearFieldPass()
{
    //implementation
}

void IMLoginView::configureComponents()
{
    //Implementation
}

void IMLoginView::keyPressEvent(QKeyEvent *event)
{
    //implementation
}


void IMLoginView::login()
{
    //implementation
}

void IMLoginView::handleError(ALFRED_ACCESS_ERROR error)
{
    //implementation   
}

void IMLoginView::userDisconnected()
{
    //implementation
}
```

I'm sorry I really can't provide the actual method code, but its closed-source. =/

Comment: One thing that strikes me as odd is that the calling convention on the symbols it's looking for is `__cdecl`, which doesn't make sense for (non-static) methods -- VC++ usually uses `__thiscall`. Another thing is that they're all interface methods. Very odd. What does [`dumpbin /symbols`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b842y285.aspx) give you for the object file that's supposed to contain those methods?

Comment: It gives me a *really* long list of symbols, both the main obj (imloginview.obj) and the moc obj (moc_imloginview.obj). The non-slot method (clearFieldPass) doesn't show up anywhere, while the slot ones shows at the moc obj as externals:


`448 00000000 UNDEF  notype ()    External     | ?login@IMLoginView@@QEAAXXZ (public: void __cdecl IMLoginView::login(void))`

Comment: Hmm. That means the linker is quite correct -- those method definitions aren't where they're supposed to be. You need to figure out why they're not being generated by the compiler (or generated with the wrong mangled name as the case may be) for the `.cpp` file in question. Can you narrow down the test case to something small enough to post here?

Comment: Any part of source code modified since you done with MinGW?

Comment: No. the same project links ok. Just tested it before answering, @AlexanderVX

Comment: They are declared in the imloginview.h header and implemented in imloginview.cpp, @Cameron, what do you mean "those method definitions aren't where they're supposed to be"?

Comment: Except for second one, obviously. They are in their respectives headers and sources, no weird mix-ups

Comment: @Tyras: I meant the actual compiled object code for those method definitions isn't showing up in the generated object file for the .cpp that contains their code-wise definitions. Otherwise you'd see the symbols in the object file. But they should be there, because the source code for their definitions is in the .cpp file from which the compiler generates the object file.

Comment: @Cameron, I just editted my post with the layout of the header and cpp of the IMLoginView class. I just removed the actual implementation code, for the sake of the confidentiality agreement i signed.

Comment: Are those methods in a separate DLL by any chance?

Comment: Can you provide an example of how `MainWindow::showConnectionErrorDialog` uses `clearFieldPass`? Does it include the `IMLoginView` header?

Comment: Its a direct call from an `IMLoginView` object allocated with `new`. Yes, it does include the `IMLoginView` header.

Comment: No, @TimoGeusch, all of them are part of the project.

Comment: Can't figure this at all... All other projects worked, just this one is giving me trouble...